# View is not rerendering, not sure why

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a ScoreView that keeps track of the current score, but I am having trouble getting it to re-render when a model attribute changes.
Here is what the view looks like:

```
  var ScoreView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');

      this.model.bind("change", function() {
        if (this.hasChanged("score")) {
          alert("score has changed");
          this.render;
        }
      });
    },

    render: function() {
      alert("drawing new score");
      return this.model.get("score");
    },

  });
```

When the score changes, the view does not re-render. I do get the alert, "score has changed", when the score changes. When I print out the contents of "this.render", the console says that the function is undefined. I think that the code thinks that the "this" in this context is the model, but I want the context to be the view. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.model.bind("change", function(model) {
    if (model.hasChanged("score")) {
      alert("score has changed");
      this.render();
    }
}, this);
```

Comment: The "this" in the if statement still refers to the this.model from the outside function. So, the this.render() is still viewed as undefined.

Comment: In backbone 0.5.x `.bind()` accepts context as third argument so `this` will refer to view

Comment: if you use 0.3.x version you can do this: `this.model.bind("change", _.bind(function(model){...}, this))`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are using 'this' in the anonymous function inside of your bind.  You should maybe try this:

```
  var self = this;
  this.model.bind("change", function() {
    if (this.hasChanged("score")) {
      alert("score has changed");
      self.render;
    }
  });
```